# Table to take entire screen in android

Tags: java, android

[image]I want my table to take the entire screen with spacing between columns and rows.
I am creating my rows dynamically in java depending upon the number of players. Where in java code I add the properties so that the table take  the entire screen. But I could not achieve it. Attached below is my code and xml file.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="views.controllers.RoundInfo">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="addRound"
        android:text="@string/addround" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="@string/roundinfo"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/maintable"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>


    public void addData() {
            numOfPlayers = currentRound.getPlayers().size();
            row = new String[numOfPlayers];
            for (int i = 0; i < numOfPlayers; i++) {
                row[i] = currentRound.getPlayers().get(i).getPlayer().getName();
            }
            col = new String[]{"Winner", "Seen", "Less", "Points"}; // get from database

            int rowCount = row.length;

            for (int i = 0; i <= rowCount; i++) {
                TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
                TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams=
                        new TableLayout.LayoutParams
                                (TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

                int leftMargin=10;
                int topMargin=2;
                int rightMargin=10;
                int bottomMargin=2;

                tableRowParams.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin);

                tableRow.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);
                // create tableRow
                for (int j = 0; j <= 4; j++) {
                    //create textView

                    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
                    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
                    EditText point = new EditText(this);
                    if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
                        textView.setText(" ");
                        tableRow.addView(textView);
                    } else if (i > 0 && j == 0) {
                        textView.setText(row[i - 1]); // Player Header
                        tableRow.addView(textView);
                    } else if (i == 0 && j != 0) {
                        textView.setText(col[j - 1]); //Game Header
                        tableRow.addView(textView);
                    } else if (i > 0 && j == 1) {
                        checkBox.setText(""); // Is Winner
                        tableRow.addView(checkBox);
                    } else if (i > 0 && j == 2) {
                        checkBox.setText(""); // Is Seen
                        tableRow.addView(checkBox);
                    } else if (i > 0 && j == 3) {
                        checkBox.setText(""); // Is Less
                        tableRow.addView(checkBox);
                    } else if (i > 0 && j == 4) {
                        point.setInputType(100); // Points
                        tableRow.addView(point);
                    }
                }
                tl.addView(tableRow);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should be using TableLayout. It will make things simpler. Just a suggestion after reading what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

if you want your table to take as much space as possible on the screen, remove margin and padding from it's parents

for example how the root layout has padding, remove this

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

This can be made a lot easier, if you reconsider how you are implementing your table.

Have empty `TableLayout` in your layout with space you want it to take in UI,

Have a separate layout for a `TableRow` which would be populated in the `TableLayout`, you will use this separate layout for row with `LayoutInflator` and populate as many rows you need

```
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
 layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_single_row, parent, false);
```

this will return a View object which you can add to the `TableLayout`

```
tableLayout.addView("you view will come here which you get from the inflater");
```

Comment: I have 5 columns, that will cover only half the screen but I want these 5 columns to cover the whole screen with padding.

Comment: I am quite new to android so not sure if i can do that..any other suggestions?

Comment: @SurabhyaAryal, can you show the screen shot of the output you are getting ?

Comment: I have uploaded the screen shoot.